# Pass additional data with Code Igniter Core Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have this core controller in my code igniter app and I want to pass a view variable to all my views.

My view is loaded in my normal controllers, so I can't load the view again in my Core controller.

So, how am I gonna do that?
I tried using `$data['fromCoreVar']` and I tried `$fromCoreVar`. Neither of both does work which is incredibly well understandable. But, I want it to work.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your core controller, declare a variable:

```
protected $data;
```

Then in your core controller, assign data to the variable like:

```
$this->data['some_index'] = 'some value';
```

In your child controller you use $data in the same way:

```
$this->data['other_index'] = 'other value';
```

and pass it all to your view:

```
$this->load->view('my_view', $this->data);
```